# merge cells in ms-access

Tags: ms-access

I'm using access 03.
let's say i'm modeling a parties database. each party has some people invited. each party also has a location and date.
when presenting the information in a form, i want to be able to merge the recurring cells. something like:

```
 _________________ ____________ ___________
|                 |            | invitee 1 |
|                 |            |-----------|
| partly location | party date | invitee 2 |
|                 |            |-----------|     
|                 |            | invitee 3 |
 ------------------------------------------
```

this is very similar to what you can do in ms-excel. is there any way to do it?

edit: sub forms have been suggested. however, it seems like when using sub forms i can only show one party at a time and i need to scroll between them using the arrows, when instead i want to show all the parties at once

Answer (score 3):

On a form you could use a main form with the Party location and party date and then have a sub-form with the list of invitees.

Comment: This is probably the best method. The same method could be done with a Report as well.

Comment: it seems like when using sub forms i can only show one party at a time and i need to scroll between them using the arrows, when instead i want to show all the parties at once

Comment: I believe you can make the main form continuous instead of a single form.  Although this might not be what you are looking for either.

Comment: You could also make a List control on the main form with all the parties, and then on selection changes on the list box force the subform to requery for the invitees.

Comment: Continuous forms can't have subforms, but there's a trick to work around it, and that's to have a non-continuous form with a subform and then display it in datasheet view. Then the + sign for the subdatasheet will display the subform. Not pretty, but quite workable.

Answer (score 2):

Access just doesn't have the feature. You can do it in a report, but not a form. There are a couple of things that might come close. If you do a datasheet subform with a datasheet parent form, you will get expanding and collapsing cells. IIRC you can expand all cells on initial presentation programmatically.

You'll have to nest datasheet subforms to get to the third column in your example.

It might also be possible to use the form view to nest a couple of subforms to the level you need, but I think at some point you're going to run into some ugly scroll bars. It will be tough to make it look decent.

I'd give the collapsing datasheets a shot. Beyond that, I think you're looking at custom, 3rd party controls, which can be a pain in Access.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, you can also take a form with an embedded subform and when you switch to datasheet view, the subform will display as the subdatasheet.

Comment: @John Mo, I know this is a very old thread but I cant find a way to do such thing in a report. You mention that it can be done in a report. Would you please show how to do it in a report?

Comment: @AykutKaraca In reports, text boxes have a Hide Duplicates property on the Format tab of the Property Sheet. The underlying recordset will have a repeating value, like "party location" from the OP. When Hide Duplicates is enabled, the value will be displayed for the first occurrence in the section (usually the Detail section) and then not again until a new value is encountered in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Not by using the datagrid view of access.

You can achive this by constracting a form with a sub form, such that the main form will display the location and date, and the sub form, the list of invitees

Answer (score 0):

A Flex Grid Control will probably do what you want but you will need to write a bit of VBA code, have a look at my Flex Grid Demo program for some examples.

Go to http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=180

HTH

Peter Hibbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that with Access 03.  Just create two tables: tblParty and tblInvitees.  The tblParty table will hold the location and date information.  The tblInvitees table will hold the invitee names.  Create a link between the two tables with a "PartyID".  You can enter information in a table, but it is best to do it in a form/subform fashion because it is easier to look at.